# Overwriting values in a pandas dataframe based on NA values from a second one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

If I have a pandas dataframe `df1` defined as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [ 1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
```

And a dataframe `df2` of the same size, same column names and index but with NA values, somewhere, both

**method A**:

```
nan_locations = np.where(df2.isnull())
df1.values[nan_locations] = np.nan
```

**method B**:

```
df1[df2.isnull()] = np.nan
```

overwrites the values in `df1` with NA's from the same locations they are in `df2`. However, if I'm doing the same with a dataframe read from an Excel file, method A doesn't always work. Could please, somebody explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Are you saying df2 is read in from Excel? If so, it may be that the "blanks" you see when you open the Excel file aren't actually NaN values after reading it in.

Comment: What mattvivier said, and there might be something to do with the indices of the DataFrame read from Excel.

Comment: I'm saying that when both dataframes are read from Excel files, the first method doesn't always work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have to do with the dtypes of the first DataFrame, whose values need to be overwritten. When the DataFrame is of mixed dtypes, the `values` attribute returns an ndarray with an upcasted dtype ([doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)), which seems to be a copy. As a result, assignment to that copy will be lost.

Here is an example of a "simple" DataFrame where method A and B both works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0, 2.0], 'b': [3.0, 4.0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0, 2.0], 'b': [np.nan, 4.0]})
```

On the other hand, this seemingly similar DataFrame only works with method B:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3.0, 4.0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [np.nan, 4.0]})
```

because the dtypes of `df1` is:

```
a      int64
b    float64
```

Hence, it might be the case that the data in your Excel file results in a DataFrame with mixed dtypes. Using proper indexers to update the contents should be preferred over direct manipulation of the low level values representation.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense! :)